# Js Module Pattern Multiple init

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

My question is about js module pattern. There is a module:

```
var moduleName = (function(self) {

  self.init() = function(){

    return self;
  }
  //Othert methods

  return self;
}(moduleName || {}));
```

Tell me please how can I create multiple initialization using this pattern (imitation of class instances)?

Comment: Just include a constructor function to construct instances in your module?

Comment: Please research before asking. There is so much literature (online) about mimicking classes in JavaScript, including some questions here on StackOverflow. Please come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Architecture my application built on the module pattern. At the moment, there arose the problem of imitation instances of classes for storing data sets. I could use a constructor pattern, but it needs to be rewritten made classes.

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

```
moduleName.init(); // Initialized once
moduleName.init(); // Initialized twice
```

If you want to create multiple modules, adjust your code as follows to follow the *factory pattern*:

```
var newModuleName = function() {
  return ( function moduleName( self ){

    self.init = function(){
      return self;
    };

    //Other methods

    return self;
  }( {} ) );
}());

var module1 = newModuleName();
var module2 = newModuleName();

module1.init();
module2.init();
```

Alternatively, use the traditional *Constructor pattern*:

```
var moduleName = function() {
  var self = this;

  if ( !( self instanceof moduleName ) ){
    return new moduleName();
  }

  self.init = function(){
    return self;
  };

  //Other methods
};
```

Comment: In the first example returns an object and not a function, so when we save it to a new area of ​​memory, get a reference to an object, not a copy of an independent module(ie, I did not get to keep data for each instance of the class). 
The second example is not suitable for me, as I will need to rewrite the already finished modules. 
Perhaps there are other solutions of the problem, or I'm not quite correctly understood your first example?